# Attendace calculation from when the person started

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a list of young people, I want to calculate their individual attendance to the programme, from the date they joined. NOTE not everyone joined at the same time.

[[image: Example of how I have set up the list, imagine 300 names and a date range that is weekly over three years]]

I can just sum from the date that I ad the name however that will mean managing every singe entry individual.

I need a formula that I can span across every user name and have the calculation pick up from when they started

NOTE if student 4 started in week 4 then their attendance will be 100% at week 4 as they have participated 1 from 1 session. However student 1 who started in week 1 will only have 75% as they started in week 1 but missed week 3

Comment: What are you using already?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have used SUMPRODUCT but that is to confusing Im trying SUMIF now but I'm not sure if I'm the right track or if there is an easier way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you percentages

```
=SUM(D4:G4)/COUNTA(D4:G4)
```

[CountA](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTA-function-7dc98875-d5c1-46f1-9a82-53f3219e2509) counts all the non-blanks in a range. So you can just sum up what they have, but only count it against non-blanks (when they start).

Comment: Now that works, ill just have to empty all the cells not used as everything is populated with 0 and changed to 1 when they attend. Thx

Comment: Ah, yeah that'd be easier than looking for the first "1" amongst 0s